# Automatic reference to Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

The following references are being automatically added to my (console application) project:

```
Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.dll
Microsoft.Data.Tools.Components.dll
```

My boss can't open the project on his machine.

As far as I know, I don't have any schema unit tests in the project, and there should be no reason for these references.

How can I resolve this? Might it be caused by the fact that I am running SSDT and my boss is not?

**Update**

The references can be removed via the `References` node in Solution Explorer, as well as via **Project Properties -> References -> Unused References...**, but when I next reopen the solution they are added back again.

This is a multi-project solution, but none of the other projects (WPF Application, 2 class libraries) have these added references.

Comment: If they're really not used your boss should be able to just edit the lines out of the project file - it's XML and easy to understand.

Comment: As noted in my update, the references are re-added when I next open the solution.

Comment: OK, but your boss can at least open the project and it'll get re-added to your copy not his. As long as you check-in the version without the extra lines and you're careful not to re-add them when you commit you'll be able to work together as a work-around until you figure out where they're coming from.

Comment: I think you can find you answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293317/where-is-the-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-unittesting-namespace-on-vs2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is being caused by SSDT, because when my boss installed SSDT on his machine he was then able to open the project without any problems.

Perhaps SSDT might be treating this as an SQL project, because there are a number of SQL files included in the project.