# Unit testing a simple class in c# with vs2012

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I am trying to `unit test` a simple function (compiles to a library) in c# VS 2012.

```
public static class Configuration
    {
        public static T DeSerialize<T>(string filePath)
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException(filePath);
            }

            using (Stream reader = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(T);
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class Test
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void deserializationTest()
        {
            var something = Configuration.DeSerialize<Item>(@"d:\CoffeeShop.Items.config");
            Console.WriteLine(something);

        }
    }
```

But, I am stuck up with `what to do next?`. What `namespaces should I import`.
Any pointers is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you create UnitTest project in that solution? Not clear where is you `Test` class located.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Sorry, how to create a `unit testing project` ? I wrote `the test-class in the same namespace` and I also `don't find any right-click option to create new unit test in vs2012`.

Comment: Should be file->new project (or something like this).. not sure what edition/version you need to have it. I believe all 2013 editions have that.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Till vs2012, we have an option `Test->New Test` and i wonder where did it go in `vs2012` ?

Comment: Hmmmm - I think I never used that feature - so no idea... I do add new projects and than add new unit test to that project from solution view... or just add new empty CS file to unit test project and add tests...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` namespace, which contains the MSTest framework classes (which you are using as implied by the `TestClass` and `TestMethod` attributes). You should then use the `Assert` class' methods to verify your test outcome. You code might look like this:
`

```
[TestMethod]
public void deserializationTest()
{
    var something = Configuration.DeSerialize<Item>(@"d:\CoffeeShop.Items.config");
    Assert.AreEqual("expected item name", something.Name);
}
```

This test verifies that the `DeSerialize` call returns an `Item` which `Name` property is equal to `"expected item name"`. Of course, this is just an assumption on how your `Item` class looks like, but you probably get the gist.

If you are getting started with unit testing in Visual Studio, this tutorial might come in handy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx

Comment: Thank you. But, i dont have a `Microsoft.visualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` dll in vs2012. It seems to have a `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll`. Where can I download the above one ?

Comment: The DLL is called: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll`. You can find more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293317/where-is-the-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-unittesting-namespace-on-vs2010

Comment: Thank you . That works. All I had to do was to go to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll` and `reference it` to my project. right click the `[TestClass] attribute` and click `Debug Tests`. `VS2012` by itself does not seem to support this `dll`.