# How to build in a unit test reference in C# project

Tags: c#, unit-testing

```
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting
```

I need to be able to unit test a class that I am building. I tried to add this class through References and it is not in the list of .NET classes.

[image]

I do not see this in the list that can be referenced into a project.

**How can I Unit Test my class without this reference?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting namespace on VS2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293317/where-is-the-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-unittesting-namespace-on-vs2010)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` assembly.

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` is the name of a namespace inside the assembly, not the name of the assembly itself. If you look at the [Assert class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.aspx) for example, you can see the assembly it is contained in.

Comment: I do not see that in my references list?

Comment: @DougHauf Have you not just added a new Unit Test project to your solution (that will already have the references for you)?

Comment: @DougHauf - Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293317/where-is-the-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-unittesting-namespace-on-vs2010) apply? I don't have VS2010 so I can't try it but if you're targeting .Net 3.5 you might have to add the reference through the file system instead.

Comment: Is this the only way to have to download a tool. Is there a built in one. The only reason that I ask is because at work I do not have the password to download files onto the system.

Comment: @DougHauf - The answers in that question suggest it should be in the VS install directory at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll`

Comment: Ok, I will have to see if I can get permission to download some files.